# Yii2 Kartik fileinput validation

Tags: file-io, yii2

I am using kartik FileInput.

I am unable to validate, i.e validation error still shows when giving it required files. Following is my code. The files are uploaded properly. but still it is shown that "Please upload a file."

View:

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'image_file[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'uploadUrl'=>Url::to('/kw/used-cars/upload'),
        'browseOnZoneClick'=>true,
        'uploadAsync'=> true,
        'maxFileCount'=> 10,
        'minFileCount'=> 4,
        'validateInitialCount'=> true,
        'overwriteInitial'=> false,

    ],
   'pluginEvents'=>[
       "fileclear" => "function() { log('fileclear'); }",
       'filebatchselected'=>'function(event, files) {

       var $input = $("#vehicles-image_file");
    //   alert($input);
// trigger upload method immediately after files are selected
$input.fileinput("upload");
}'
   ],
    'options' => [
        'accept' => 'image/*',
        'multiple'=>true

    ]
   ]);
```

Action:

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new Vehicles();
    $model->image_file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'image_file');
    // print_R($model->fld_image);exit;
    $images = '';
    if ($model->image_file) {
        foreach ($model->image_file as $file) {
            $img_name = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();

            $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $img_name . '.' . $file->extension);
            $images .= $img_name.'.'.$file->extension.'###';

        }
        $model->image_file = $images;
        return true;
        //return json_encode($model->image_file);

    }
}
```

Model Settings:

```
  [['image_name'], 'string', 'max' => 2556],
        [['image_file'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'jpeg, jpg, png,     gif','skipOnEmpty'=>false, 'maxSize'=>20*1024*1024, 'maxFiles'=>1000],
```

Upload Function:

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new Vehicles();
    $model->image_file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'image_file');
    // print_R($model->fld_image);exit;
    $images = '';
    if ($model->image_file) {
        foreach ($model->image_file as $file) {
            $img_name = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();

            $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $img_name . '.' . $file->extension);
            $images .= $img_name.'.'.$file->extension.'###';

        }
        $model->image_file = $images;
        return true;
        //return json_encode($model->image_file);

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is some conflicting in JS/jQuery files. Check console if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

in your `model` for `image_file` you should put `'skipOnEmpty'=>true,` the uploaded image will be in `$_FILE`.